# How can I use ipv6 to access website while only ipv4 is supported in my network?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm using Ubuntu Linux as my operating system.
In my network only the ipv4 is suported, and I need to access some website through ipv6. How can I do it, is there a way to tunnel from the ipv4 to ipv6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a few options - You can use a  IPV4-6 gateway such as the one provided by [sixxs](http://www.sixxs.net/tools/gateway/) - the advantage of this being that you KNOW for certain its ipv6 and with almost no config . This is what i recommend IF you just need to check websites and not other internet connected resources.

While teredo - is an option - install miredo on a linux system, and ipv6 will work, with almost no config needed, but the performance is terrible compared to a proper tunnel  so you're better off going with a dedicated tunnel broker - hurricane electric is what most people do, but i tend to use [gogo6](http://www.gogo6.com/) - they have a client that works behind a nat, though you'd need to compile it, and configure it as per the instructions on the site.

Answer (score 2):

If protocol 41 is open through your firewall you may be able to use a 6in4 tunnel.  I used the [Shorewall 6xx4 tunnels](http://www.shorewall.net/6to4.htm) documentation to help me configure IPv6.

My tunnel is running on my [OpenWRT Wifi router](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-ipv6-6to4-on-openwrt/).  I started off using the anycast address to open a tunnel, and switched to [a dedicated tunnel](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-ipv6-part-2/).  Latency is still higher than IPv4.  My ISP still doesn't know when they will be ready for IPv6.  However, I am ready for [World IPv6 day.](http://test-ipv6.com/ipv6day.html)